# User "system:serviceaccount:default:flink" cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-rbac

I am trying to call k8s api in one k8s pod. But hit the following permission issue:

```
User "system:serviceaccount:default:flink" cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope.
```

In my yaml file, I already have specified the `Role` & `RoleBinding`. What do I miss here?

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: flink
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: zeppelin-server-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "services", "configmaps", "deployments", "nodes"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "update", "patch", "list", "delete", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["roles", "rolebindings"]
  verbs: ["bind", "create", "get", "update", "patch", "list", "delete", "watch"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: zeppelin-server-role-binding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: flink
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: zeppelin-server-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: is your pod using given service account? show us your deployment YAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deploying zeppelin-server on Kubernetes, right? Your yaml file with the service account looks good as I suppose, however to be sure that this works, you should follow the next steps:

- `kubectl get clusterrole`

and you should get `zeppelin-server-role` role.

- check if your account '**flink**' has a binding to clusterrole "zeppelin-server-role"

`kubectl get clusterrole clusterrolebinding`

if there is no, you can create it by the following command:

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding zeppelin-server-role-binding --clusterrole=zeppelin-server-role --serviceaccount=default:flink`

- finally, check if you really act as this account:

`kubectl get deploy flink-deploy -o yaml`

if you can't see the settings "serviceAccount" and "serviceAccountName" from the output something like:

```
...
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
restartPolicy: Always
schedulerName: default-scheduler
securityContext: {}
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
...
```

then add this account you want flink to use:

`kubectl patch deploy flink-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'`

Comment: Thanks @Bazhikov, it looks like I miss the clusterrolebinding, so I have to run this command: "kubectl create clusterrolebinding zeppelin-server-role-binding --clusterrole=zeppelin-server-role --serviceaccount=default:flink", after that it works. What I confused is that I have already create the clusterrolebinding in my yaml file, why it doesn't take effect